# Oracle Database multiple table delete problem

Tags: sql, database, oracle, cascading-deletes

I have 2 table which id of t1 is referenced as t1_fk in t2. When i want to delete row from t1 i am getting error that i have child reference in t2. I would like to make it within one execute.

I found oracle SQL solution:

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_fk;
```

but this does not work for me neither in node-oracle_db, neither in sql developer. It throws "SQL COMMAND NOT FINISHED PROPERLY".

Can anybody help please?

### UPDATE(Solved):

Thanks to following comments I was able to fix it following there were two constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE t2
drop CONSTRAINT c_t1_fk;

ALTER TABLE t2
  ADD CONSTRAINT c_t1_fk 
  FOREIGN KEY (t1_fk) 
  REFERENCES FILTER_PROFIL(id) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE t3
drop CONSTRAINT c_t1_fk;

ALTER TABLE t3 
  ADD CONSTRAINT c_t1_fk 
  FOREIGN KEY (t1_fk) 
  REFERENCES FILTER_PROFIL(id) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

After changing constraint i simply did following:

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id=:id
```

And everything worked now.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in *one go*; Oracle deletes one table at a time. So:

- delete children first (because of foreign key constraints)
- delete masters next

If foreign key constraint is declared as `ON DELETE CASCADE`, then yes - you could do it just by

- delete masters

as *cascading* would take care about children.

Comment: actually. SQL developer is ok now using on delete cascade. But when i call that query using node-oracledb it still shouting : DELETE FROM FILTER_PROFIL where id=:id
    : ORA-02292: integrity constraint

Comment: There are probably other FK constaints which are not set to be deleted. As Oracle reports FK name that was violated, that is your starting point fir further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your sample setup

```
create table t1
(id number primary key);

create table t2
(id number primary key,
 t1_id number);
 
alter table t2 add constraint "FK" foreign key (t1_id) references t1 (id); 

insert into t1 (id) values(1);
insert into t1 (id) values(2);

insert into t2 (id,t1_id) values (1,1); 
insert into t2 (id,t1_id) values (2,1); 
insert into t2 (id,t1_id) values (3,1); 

insert into t2 (id,t1_id) values (4,2);
```

Now you want to delete from `T1` the rows with `id` 1 and 2

```
delete from t1
where id in (1,2);
```

but you fail with an error of

> ORA-02292: integrity constraint (xxx.FK) violated - child record found

You need to *change* the constraint to `on delete cascade`, which will delete the child rows after the deletion of the parent.

```
alter table t2 drop constraint "FK";
alter table t2 add constraint "FK" foreign key (t1_id) references t1 (id) on delete cascade;
```

and delete again

```
delete from t1
where id in (1,2);
```

you get

```
 2 rows deleted.
```

... and the table `T2` is empty as well